Spring Boot Swagger expanding generated schema programaitclly
I want to use reflection and expand field schemas (set example value, description etc...) scoped to a single definition for example:
AUTHENTICATION definition

password field in all method parameters annotated with @RequestBody (all DTO's) will share the same schema definition

In all @RequestBody method parameters search for password and expand metadata


In the above example "example values" are changed
Why do I want to do it this way? So I avoid putting annotations on each API operation or DTO.
I have multiple swagger definitions:

I tried the following.
For example defining AUTHENTICATION with a operationCustomizer
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi authGroup() {
        return createOpenApiGroup(OpenAPIGroup.AUTHENTICATION)
                .addOperationCustomizer(authCustomizer())
                .build();
    }

Here is the customizer
private OperationCustomizer authCustomizer() {

        Set<String> value = Set.of("username", "password");

        return ((operation, handlerMethod) -> {
            Arrays.stream(handlerMethod
                    .getMethodParameters())
                    .filter(methodParameter -> methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(RequestBody.class))
                    .findAny()
                    .ifPresent(methodParameter -> {
                        Arrays.stream(methodParameter
                                .getParameterType()
                                .getDeclaredFields())
                                .filter(classField -> value.contains(classField.getName().toLowerCase()))
                                .forEach(classField -> {
                                    final var schema = operation.getRequestBody()
                                            .getContent()
                                            .get("application/json")
                                            .getSchema();
                                    final var yo = schema
                                            .getProperties()
                                            .get(classField.getName());
                                    System.out.println("");
                                });
                    });

            return operation;
        });
    }

Issue is I get a NullPointerException at
final var yo = schema.getProperties().get(classField.getName());
